# CakePHP 2.5 Validation isUnique

Tags: cakephp

I have been racking my brain for hours trying to figure this out. Basically i have a table called customers. I can create new customers with no issues but when it comes to editing them isUnique always says they already exist, obviously i know that but i want it to be unique compared to all other records.

model: Customer.php

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'uniqueName' => array(
                        'rule' => 'isUnique',
                        'message' => 'Customer already exists',
                        'on' => 'create'
                    )
    ),
            'reference' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
        'uniqueReference' => array(
                        'rule' => 'isUnique',
                        'message' => 'Customer reference already exists',
                        'on' => 'create'
                    )
    ),
);
```

Controller: CustomerController.php

```
    public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Customer->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid customer'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
                    $this->Customer->id = $id;
        if ($this->Customer->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Customer.' . $this->Customer->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Customer->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

View: edit.ctp

```
<div class="users form index col-md-9">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Customer',array('class'=>'form-horizontal','role' => 'form')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Customer'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('reference');
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Update'),array('class'=>'btn btn-medium btn-success')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions index col-md-3">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

        <li><?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $this->Form->value('Customer.id')), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $this->Form->value('Customer.id'))); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Customers'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Customer'), array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the solutions i have found in other posts never seem to work which is so frustrating.

Thanks for any help
Steve

Comment: Most likely you forgot to pass along the id on edit. Or get's removed somewhere where it shouldn't. Otherwise it always works just fine for both add and edit AFAIK.

Comment: you have your 'uniqueName' validation 2 times in your code, btw

Comment: Hi @mark I have just checked and the ID is being passed onto the edit. The data is being returned correctly just seems like the isUnique errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok im a bit of an idiot!

My Database didnt have auto increment on the ID so was and issue with that all works fine now.